# spam keywords to block in mail

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam

Can anybody suuggest me a list of keywords which i can block in mails which are sent from my postfix mail server.I wanna include them in my postfix header checks and body checks file.

Comment: This kind of blocking tends not to be very effective because the spammers change what they send to avoid using the keywords in your list; hence "v14gr4".  You might get a more useful answer if you re-phrase your question to "How can I best stop spam being sent through my Postfix server?"

Comment: Hold on a moment... You've referred to emails that are *sent* through your server twice now. Your best bet is to kick the spammers off your service, *not* to play around with word lists. Spam, after all, is about consent, not content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spammers tend to change their wording often to avoid such blocking, so it'll be hard to build a blocking list that will work for a long time. I would have a look at spamassassin, an opensource product that will update its own settings to adapt to the changes that spammers make.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion jenny D but i need a list of words because spamassassin is not required in my mail server because we need to only send mails from it,and speed is an issue.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that a list of words is highly unlikely to help you. If there were such a list that worked, there would be no spam problem. I think you need to reframe the question. Who  is it that you're afraind will send spam? Who is using the server - is it people in your company, or is it your customers, or is it maybe used to send email from forms on a web server, or all three? Whatever solution you come up with will be more complex than a list of words and will depend on what type of spam problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: ok thanks for your help i will take a look at spamassassin.